# Figuring out if an entire column in a Pandas dataframe is the same value or not

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that works just fine. I am trying to figure out how to tell if a column with a label that I know if correct does not contain all the same values.

The code

```
below errors out for some reason when I want to see if the column contains -1 in each cell
# column = "TheColumnLabelThatIsCorrect"
# df = "my correct dataframe"

# I get an () takes 1 or 2 arguments but 3 is passed in error    
if (not df.loc(column, estimate.eq(-1).all())):
```

I just learned about .eq() and .all() and hopefully I am using them correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a syntax issue - see docs for [`.loc`/indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html). Specifically, you want to be using `[]` instead of `()`

You can do something like

```
if not df[column].eq(-1).all():
    ...
```

If you want to use `.loc` specifically, you'd do something similar:

```
if not df.loc[:, column].eq(-1).all():
    ...
```

Also, note you don't need to use `.eq()`, you can just do `(df[column] == -1).all())` if you prefer.

Comment: i see. I was using .loc when I didn't need to.

Answer (score 1):

You could drop duplicates and if you get only one record it means all records are the same.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [1, 1, 1, 1]})
len(df['col'].drop_duplicates()) == 1
> True
```

Answer (score 1):

Question not as clear. Lets try the following though

Contains only -1 in each cell

```
df['estimate'].eq(-1).all()
```

Contains  -1 in any cell

```
df['estimate'].eq(-1).any()
```

Filter out -1 and all columns

```
df.loc[df['estimate'].eq(-1),:]
```

Answer (score 0):

`df['column'].value_counts()` gives you a list of all unique values and their counts in a column. As for checking if all the values are a specific number, you can do that by dropping duplicates and checking the length to be 1.

```
len(set(df['column'])) == 1
```